# Storing multiple records cakePHP way

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

So there is Event table in the database that holds information about one single event(like date, time, customer, task, materials etc.). One event can only happen on one day, but in the event creation form, user is able to create repeated events. Basically user inserts the information as if it was a single event, but also has a possiblity to select the end day and days on which the event should be repeated.

Here is the array which I get when the start date is 2013-10-01 the end date is 2013-10-15 and the events have to be repeated from Monday to Friday:

```
array(
    'Event' => array(
        'project_id' => '57',
        'user_id' => '19',
        'hours' => '2',
        'minutes' => '30',
        'assignment' => 'Pick the kids up',
        'date' => '2013-10-01',
        'start_time' => array(
            'hour' => '17',
            'min' => '30'
        ),
        'finish_time' => array(
            'hour' => '00',
            'min' => '00'
        ),
        'repeat' => '1',
        'finish_date' => '2013-10-15',
        'weekdays' => array(
            (int) 0 => '1',
            (int) 1 => '2',
            (int) 2 => '3',
            (int) 3 => '4',
            (int) 4 => '5'
        )
    )
)
```

I just wonder what is the most cakePHP like way to go about in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

store it in an Events table, and put the occurrence in an Event_Ties table